# How to show a loading icon when a frame is loading

Tags: jquery

I have got two frames in a HTML page .

During the period when  frame is loading i wanted to show a loading icon , and when frame is completed loading i wanted to hide that .

i have tried this way

```
<h5 class="element-title">Indices </h5>
  <iframe width="100"  height="200" src="http://www.umich.edu" onload="onLoadHandlerforindices();" >
</iframe>

<h5 class="element-title">My Data </h5>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" onload="onLoadHandlerformydata();" ></iframe>
</iframe>

<img id="loadImg" src="http://www.cuisson.co.uk/templates/cuisson/supersize/slideshow/img/progress.BAK-FOURTH.gif" alt="loading...">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#loadImg").hide();
});

function onLoadHandlerforindices()
{
    $("#loadImg").show();
}

function onLoadHandlerformydata()
{
    $("#loadImg").show();
}
```

But the icon is not being shown

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/11Lnatr6/3/

Comment: `onload` is triggered after the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic should be inverted. The `onload` event triggers after the target element(s) are loaded. Try showing the image and, when the iframe is loaded, hide it! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11Lnatr6/4/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#loadImg").show();
});

function onLoadHandlerforindices()
{


    $("#loadImg").hide();
}

function onLoadHandlerformydata()
{


    $("#loadImg").hide();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fiddle , but i couldn't see the loading icon when the frame is being loaded .

Comment: If I understood well, you want to show a loading gif *while* the iframe is loading and, when it is loaded, hide the gif. Is this right?

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with the visible area of the fiddle. Look this one (I added some css): http://jsfiddle.net/11Lnatr6/5/

Answer (score 0):

The `onload=""` event is triggered after the page finished loading, not at the start.

Count down how many iframes have to load and hide the image when all are loaded:

```
<h5 class="element-title">Indices </h5>
  <iframe width="100"  height="200" src="http://www.umich.edu" onload="onFrameLoaded();" >
</iframe>

<h5 class="element-title">My Data </h5>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" onload="onFrameLoaded();" ></iframe>
</iframe>

<img id="loadImg" src="http://www.cuisson.co.uk/templates/cuisson/supersize/slideshow/img/progress.BAK-FOURTH.gif" alt="    loading...">    

<script type="text/javascript">
var iframesToLoad = 2;
function onFrameLoaded() {
    iframesToLoad--;
    if ( iframesToLoad == 0 )
        $("#loadImg").hide();
}
</script>
```